# Can't make google http request from joomla site

Tags: php, api, http, google-analytics

I'm doing some experimenting with the *Google Analytics API* and it's coming along nicely (just following their Hello Analytics turorial for now). The code runs fine up to the point where I'm at when i run it on my old dummy domain, but when I try to do it fromm a site I'm currently developing (with joomla) I get problems with the http-requests.

I give the user a link to google where I can choose google account and grant access to GA etc and when it redirects to my site I get nothing. It loads for a while then sends me to my sites 404 page.

My code looks like this (it's inside the default.php in a view of a component. I took away the defined(j_exec) or die() for testing purposes):

```
<?php



require_once 'libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'libraries/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';
require_once 'libraries/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

$session = JFactory::getSession();

$client = new Google_Client(); 
//$client->setAccessType('online');
$client->setApplicationName('sdffdgdfg');
$client->setClientId('my id ;)');
$client->setClientSecret('dsfdsf');
$client->setRedirectUri('asdsdf');
$client->setDeveloperKey('fdfg');
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');

// Set the client libraries to convert all the API responses from associative arrays into objects.
$client->setUseObjects(true);


//$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);
if( isset( $_GET['code'] ) ){

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code'] );
    $session->set('token', $client->getAccessToken());
    //i took away the redirect here cuz i wanted to see that the code actually came :)


}

$token = $session->get('token');
if( isset( $token ) ){

    $client->setAccessToken($session->get('token'));


}

if( !$client->getAccessToken() ){

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    print "<a class ='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect me!</a>";

}else{
    echo "WE'RE IN!!";
    //$analytics = new apiAnalyticsService($client);
    //runMainDemo($analytics);

}


?>
```

The problem stops if I comment the line $client->authenticate($_GET['code'] ); so I've followed that trail and finally come to a line saying

```
$request = Google_Client::$io->makeRequest(new Google_HttpRequest(self::OAUTH2_TOKEN_URI, 'POST', array(), array(
          'code' => $code,
          'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
          'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUri,
          'client_id' => $this->clientId,
          'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret
      )));
```

This line resides in Google_OAuth2.php line 96. So something goes wrong with the request and it time out. What can I do about it? This is pretty much as far as my own problem solving takes me so I really need some help with this! Could it be something to do with joomla? Or my server configuration? (Not same as my dummy domain..)

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: it's look like redirect url not found you have passed

Comment: yeah, but the thing is if I comment away the $client->authenticate all is fine except I can't authenticate in that case..

Comment: try to check !empty( $_GET['code'] )

Comment: thx but it didn't work.. I'm guessing you mean instead of isset..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized due to a closed firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to say that this is solved. I emailed my server provider before posting here and they told me that they had nothing to do with this. I then emailed them again (like 2 weeks after posting here) and they said my firewall was closed. When they opened it I got in :)